# Mac OS: Ошибка при обновлении ruby gems

Tags: ruby, gems, zlib

При попытке обновления возникает ошибка несовместимости версий **Zlib**.

```
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::VersionError)
    incompatible version
```

`ruby` сейчас установлен через `rvm`. Версия `2.5.1`.

Через `brew` все версии `ruby` удалены.

Через тот же `brew` установлены библиотеки `lzlib`, `zlib`, `libzip`, `libtool` (все, что нагуглилось).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил `zlib` из `brew`:

```
brew uninstall --force zlib
```

Установил `zlib` из [исходников](https://www.zlib.net):

```
tar xvf <архив>
cd <распакованный архив>
./configure
make
make install
```

Затем переустановил руби:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1
```

---

Помог [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511069/8899246).

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin принято.